# Smarty assign variable - returns zero

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I'm having an issue... I'm trying to do simply assign value to a variable in Smarty, but it always returns 0. Any idea why?

```
{if (strstr($pid, 'XXX') == true) || ($did == 256)}
......Step 1 reached......
    {if (strstr($pid, 'MTG') == true) || ($key_name == 'mtgfc')}
        ......step 2 reached.......
        {assign var="css-tag" value="mtg"}
        <p>css-tag = {$css-tag}</p>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

this is what I get as a result:

```
......Step 1 reached......

......Step 2 reached......

css-tag = 0
```

Why it doesn't assign the value to the variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in php, you can't use a minus sign in the name of a variable. Use underscore instead:

```
{assign var="css_tag" value="mtg"}
```